# Unity 3D (5) Travando no IOS

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo no Unity 3D, mas quando rodo fica ótimo no PC , Android, navegador, Linux, Windows, mas quando rodo no IOS, ele fica travando. Coloquei só um cubo e continuou travando. OBS: Reduzi o erro para caber. Veja o código:

```
 float velocityX;
 float velocityY;
 void Update(){
    velocityX = 0.2f;
    velocityY = 0;
    pos.x = velocityX;
    pos.y = velocityY;

    transform.Translate(pos);
}
```

É só este código, já tentei com FixedUpdate.

Quando eu executo o jogo no emulador agora recebo o erro:

```
Process:               Xcode [1417]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.1 (7703)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7703000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812230896
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1417]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Users/pedrosoares/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4AC0B159-E3E1-4A44-8B7B-66346F44C0B8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AA467879-CC70-4BB8-972F-6E1EA7DF154E/mp.app/mp
PlugIn Identifier:       pedro.soares.pong.mp
PlugIn Version:          1.0 (1.0)

Date/Time:             2015-05-18 09:16:55.683 -0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        511FEBBC-94B3-4DD2-29FD-475DE8150609

Sleep/Wake UUID:       667983E5-8B70-46EE-8891-C98A735AC253

Time Awake Since Boot: 34000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       850 seconds

Crashed Thread:        20

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x000000012a9e9000

kernel messages:
-4 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x12a9e9000): p=1417[Xcode] final status 0x3004200, denying page sending SIGKILL
-4 sec              CODE SIGNING: process 1417[Xcode]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x12a9e9000 from offset 0x14cd000 in file "/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4AC0B159-E3E1-4A44-8B7B-66346F44C0B8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AA467879-CC70-4BB8-972F-6E1EA7DF154E/mp.app/mp" (cs_mtime:1431951402.0 == mtime:1431951402.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)

VM Regions Near 0x12a9e9000:
    MALLOC_LARGE           000000012742f000-000000012951c000 [ 32.9M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> mapped file            000000012951c000-000000012b609000 [ 32.9M] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4AC0B159-E3E1-4A44-8B7B-66346F44C0B8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AA467879-CC70-4BB8-972F-6E1EA7DF154E/mp.app/mp
    JS JIT generated code  000058ff36400000-000058ff36401000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D1002

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 2
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 12107
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 7

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=414.1M resident=131.5M(32%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=282.6M(68%)
Writable regions: Total=1.3G written=67.4M(5%) resident=90.4M(7%) swapped_out=39.2M(3%) unallocated=1.2G(93%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
Activity Tracing                     2048K
CG backing stores                    6408K
CG image                              780K
CG shared images                      304K
CoreAnimation                          72K
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreImage                               8K
CoreUI image data                     144K
Dispatch continuations               8192K
Foundation                             16K
Image IO                              136K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              182.9M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                         32K
OpenCL                                 24K
SQLite page cache                    1792K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                33.7M
VM_ALLOCATE                          17.3M
WebKit Malloc                         464K
__DATA                               45.3M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                          106.6M
__TEXT                              307.6M
__UNICODE                             552K
mapped file                         111.1M
shared memory                           4K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.9G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      885.7M


Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B18, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121,33 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

Comment: Sugiro que coloque onde você chama essa estrutura, a configuração do dispositivo e o resultado do Profiler para que as pessoas possam te ajudar com a resposta exata para o problema.

Comment: Pedro, apesar da sua pergunta ter sido suspensa como ampla, isso não significa que ela foi "jogada fora". Edite-a para incluir mais informações sobre o problema específico (como o @Nils sugeriu), que ela pode ser reaberta. :)

Comment: @Pedro Soares, agora você está misturando dois erros na mesma pergunta. Um é a otimização do código no iOS, o outro é o crash do xcode. Sugiro abrir uma pergunta paralela para isso. Vou atualizar a minha resposta de acordo com tua primeira pergunta, e depois vou estudar o que foi o motivo do crash.

Answer (score 2):

Poder ser um monte de problemas, desde sua versão do Unity até a configuração e estado do teu dispositivo iOS.

Recomendo rodar o profiler do Unity para investigar este problema mais a fundo.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html

Espeficicamente para iPhone
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-InternalProfiler.html

Se você não conseguir seguir a partir destes dados, sugiro que compartilhe mais informações, como o modelo/configuração do dispositivo. E os dados resultados do Profiler. E onde em teu código você chama esse procedimento, tem uma grande diferença de você colocar no Update, FixedUpdate, e por ai vai.*

Com um pouco de sorte pode ser algo facilmente resolvível na configuração da build. Ou adicionar o código `Application.targetFrameRate = 60` (vale lembrar que iOS trava em 30 frames por segundo por padrão as aplicações).

*Tome cuidado que tua pergunta tem pouca informação, não é muito específica e muitas respostas possíveis, passível de ser bloqueada pela moderação por causa disso.

Comment: Nils, fantástico o trabalho que você vem fazendo com a Unity aqui na comunidade (mesmo com perguntas - ao menos as mais recentes - de mais baixa qualidade). :)

Comment: Muito obrigado, Luiz Vieira. Eu sempre gostei da forma que são feita as soluções aqui no stackoverflow, mas acho que só agora fiquei mais confiante para responder(ou apareceram assuntos que me sinto mais a vontade respondendo e dá tempo de responder, e tem diversas comunidades maneiras), além de ter empurrado todo mundo que está aprendendo lá no youtube para cá.

Comment: É isso ai. Por favor, continue com o bom trabalho! []s :)

Comment: Tentei com um Iphone 4, Ipad 2, Ipad mini, Iphone 6 Emulator. A mesma coisa, se necessário posso postar um vídeo.

Comment: @PedroSoares - Você conseguiu rodar o Profiler? Poderia mandar o resultado na pergunta, por favor? O vídeo vai servir para visualizar o problema, mas preciso de alguns dados por trás para descobrir o que está acontecendo de fato (ou você pode testar a targetframerate/configurações da build que nem falei).

Comment: Agora que eu fui instalar o profile o emulador trava quando vou executar o jogo. Vou colocar o erro na pergunta.

Comment: Coloca o erro em outra pergunta, são coisas diferentes. Mas já que você está usando o xcode, você pode usar o analyser